# Illustrator CS5: Multiline text along a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do you create multiline text along a curve?

I'm using the Type On Path tool for single-line text, but is there a way to make the text multiline?

Answer (score 4):

Draw two paths.

Select both paths, choose Type > Threaded Text > Create.

Add the text to the paths.

[image: text paths]

Comment: I wasn't able to make the text continue on the second line. So I just created another line and started a new text...

Comment: You have to select both lines and choose Type > Threaded Text > Create in order for the text to flow between lines.

Answer (score 0):

In illustrator CC 2015 you can also click the box with the little + in it and click on another path to thread text from path to path.